# How do they simplify the autocorrelation function?

Tags: statistical-inference, correlation, stationary-processes

In my book they state that

> ...the autocorrelation function can be defined as
>
> $$r_X(s,t)=\frac{\text{Cov}[X(s),X(t)]}{\sqrt{\text{var}[X(s)]\text{var}[X(t)]}},\tag
>  1$$
>
> where $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ correspond to values of a stochastic process
>   at time points $t$ and $s$. Under the assumption of stationarity (the
>   distribution of $\{X(t)_{t}^{t+h}\}$ is independent of $t$ for a fixed
>   $h$), the ACF only depends on the time lag, $h$. This means that
>
> $$r_X(h)=r_X(t,t+h)=\frac{\text{Cov}[X(t),X(t+h)]}{\text{var}[X(t)]}.\tag2$$

**Questions:**

1. Shouldn't the notation be $r_X(X(s),X(t))$ and not $r_X(s,t)?$
2. I don't understand why they can go from  $(1)$ to $(2)$ like that. In the numerator they replace $X(s)$ by $X(t)$ and $X(t)$ by$X(t+h)$ but in the denominator they **don't** replace the $X(t)$ with $X(t+h).$ Why?

Comment: 2. They skipped a step; you start with $\text{Var}(X(t+h))$ in the denominator, and by stationarity note that this is equal to $\text{Var}(X(t))$, so you make that replacement.

Comment: @MikeEarnest So why can't I do the same thing in the numerator and why do I need to start in the denominator? Why isn't $\text{Cov}[X(t+h)]=\text{Cov}[X(t)]$?

Comment: The numerator has $\text{Cov}[X(t),X(t+h)]$. We know that $X(t+h)$ is equal in distribution to $X(t)$, but that does not imply that $X(t+h)$ is correlated with $X(t)$ the same way $X(t)$ is correlated with $X(t)$. That is, just because $A$ and $B$ have the same distribution, that does not imply $\text{Cov}(A,C)=\text{Cov}(B,C)$, because  $A$ and $B$ could be  correlated with $C$ in different ways.